# case when exists null then false

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query:

```
select (case when exists (select null from dual) then 'row exists'
             else '2'
       )
from dual
```

What (`select null from dual`) is exists.

I want to `select null from dual` is not exists for my first query return is 2, but don't not check this subquery is not null, because my subquery returned more than one row.

Comment: What is your question?  It is unclear.

Comment: Syntax error. (Missing `end`.)

Comment: I've read your question several times but can't really tell what you are trying to achieve. Your use of double negatives in the context of a question on NOT EXISTS is  . . . .tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that you are confused that `exists (select null from dual)` is a true condition.

Well, that is how SQL works.  `exists` is checking to see if any *rows* are returned from the subquery.  By definition, `select . . . from dual` is going to return one row.  That is what `dual` does.

You are probably confused by the `select null`.  Well, I also don't like that.  So I typically write this as:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from dual) then 'row exists'
             else '2'
       )
from dual;
```

The `1` is arbitrary.  But, it is the value of "true" in many programming languages and it is really easy to type.

Comment: how can I find an alternative method?